# C Linked list how can I remove a node

Tags: c, string, pointers, linked-list, char

So I had a problem with the "String name" I fixed it, now I would like to
add a function that's removes the node by its ID, so I tried to make a function that locates the node with the requested ID, It did not go well because it does not track the ID I entered.
Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct stringData {

    int id;
    char *name;
    int payment;

    struct stringData *next;
} Node;

Node *addEmployee(int id, char *name, int payment) {
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->id = id;
    newNode->name = strdup(name);
    newNode->payment = payment;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}


void insert(Node **link, Node *newNode) {
    newNode->next = *link;
    *link = newNode;
}

void removeEmployee(Node *head, int id){
    while (head != NULL){
            head = head->next;
        if(head ->id == id){
            printf("The employee exists.");
        }
        printf("The employee does not exists.");
    }
}


void printList(Node *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("----------------------------------\n");
        printf("Name: %s\n", head->name);
        printf("ID: %d\n", head->id);
        printf("Payment: %d\n", head->payment);
        printf("----------------------------------\n");
        head = head->next;
    }
}



int main(void)
{
    int id;
    char name[42];
    int payment;
    int input;

    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;
    Node *n;


    n = addEmployee(1, "Dor", 5000);
    insert(&head, n);
    tail = n;
    n = addEmployee(2, "David", 10000);
    insert(&head, n);
    tail = n;


    printList(head);

    removeEmployee(head, 2);



    while((input != 4)){
        printf("\nPlease select 1 option:\n1) Add an employee - type 1\n2) Remove an employee - type 2\n3) Show a list of employees - type 3\n4) Exit - type 4\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);
    switch(input){
    case 1:
        printf("\nPlease enter the employee's id: ");
        scanf("%d", &id);
        printf("\nPlease enter the employee's name: ");
        scanf("%41s",name);
        printf("\nPlease enter the employee's payment: ");
        scanf("%d", &payment);

        n = addEmployee(id, name, payment);
        insert(&head, n);
        tail = n;
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Please enter the ID of the employee you would like to remove: ");
        scanf("%d", &id);
        break;

    case 3:
        printList(head);
        break;

    case 4:
        printf("Good-bye");
        break;

    default:
        printf("This is not an option!");
        break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I do not know how to get into it, I'm not that familiar with this subject so It would be very helpful to also see some examples.

Comment: You have `char *name;` ... `scanf("%s", name);` but you have not allocated any memory. I suggest `char name[42];` ... `scanf("%41s", name);`

Comment: You also have a fault in `newNode->name = name;` because each node will point to the same name (the one most recently entered). I suggest `newNode->name = strdup(name);` if supported or use `malloc`  and `strcpy` if not.

Comment: I tried to change it to strdup and its working, you think I should also allocate memory?

Comment: `strdup` does allocate memory, but it is a non-standard function. Hence the suggestion to write the same lines in full that `strdup` does. It might  not be in your library.

Comment: Now I have another question, I would like to bubble-sort the list.

Comment: Please ask a new question, showing what you have tried.

Comment: Changed the subject again, I tried to do this one.

Comment: Q: `How do I remove a node?` A:You remove a node by changing **the pointer that points to it**

Comment: I tried to do that `void removeEmployee(Node *head, int id){
    while (head != NULL){
        if(head ->id == id){
            head = head->next;
            printf("Employee deleted successfully.");
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
}` And it's does not working

Comment: Remove requires two things: free the node, and fix the link that used to point to it.

Comment: To free the node I need to do ```free(head);```? And what do you mean by fixing the pointer

Comment: If there's a previous node, then it's next pointer must be changed.  If there is no previous node, then the head of the list must be changed.